# Waiting for render events with Selenium and React

Tags: c#, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting started with using Selenium to test a React application that I have built.

In most simple JavaScript applications it is trivial to wire up a test where one uses the `WebDriverWait` class to wait for some event to signal that the test can proceed to the next step.

For example:

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationUrl}/Dashboard");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(d => d.Title.StartsWith("dashboard", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    //Can do next thing....

    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

However things get a bit more complicated if we want to test a React application. Given that each component in your React application *will each individually invoke* [their own lifecycle events](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), in their own time, it is extremely difficult to know when a given control has completed its `Render()` lifecycle.

I have played with a simple solution like:

```
//Add something like this to each React component
componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.document.hasMyComponentMounted)
        window.document.hasMyComponentMounted = true;
}
```

and then I can do something like this in my tests:

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationUrl}/Dashboard");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(d => js.ExecuteScript("return window.document.hasHomeMounted"));

    //Can do next thing....

    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

but this seems like a kinda sucky solution.

Has anyone encountered the same problem or know of potential workarounds (except for just using `Thread.Sleep()`)?

Comment: In general you just wait for certain conditions to be true.  If the events never update the DOM, then you'd have to do something like you are doing here.  WebDriverWait will throw a timeout if the condition is not met within your timeout period, or a stale element exception if items are found but are changing due to a client side loop which hasn't finished yet.  (call again in that case...)

Comment: I would suggest you to use Cypress rather than Selenium. Cypress have got some of the powerful functions, one being https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax. The only drawback is you have to code in javascript, jquery which I guess should not be a problem at all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have written extensive automation for a React.js application, and as you mentioned, it was a very difficult problem waiting for components to render.

There is no concrete solution that can fix every issue with this. The solution you mentioned, to wait for components to mount, is a good one. You can make it cleaner by wrapping it in with WebDriver calls so that they automatically wait for the components to mount, and you do not have to specify that code in your test cases.

Here's an idea:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions()
{
    public static void WaitForComponents(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(d => js.ExecuteScript("return window.document.hasHomeMounted"));
    }

    public static void GoToUrl(this IWebDriver driver, string url)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        driver.WaitForComponents();
    }
}
```

Then, your test case will look like:

```
using WebDriverExtensions;

using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

    driver.GoToUrl($"{Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationUrl}/Dashboard");


    //Can do next thing....

    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

If the component you are checking is constantly changing, i.e. `hasHomeMounted` only works on the Home page, the solution is a little uglier. You could try something that takes a component name as a parameter to check if it is mounted:

```
    public static void WaitForComponent(this IWebDriver driver, string componentName)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(d => js.ExecuteScript($"return window.document.has{componentName}Mounted"));
    }
```

As I mentioned, there is no catch-all way to accomplish this, and using `Thread.Sleep()` everywhere is not advisable. Your solution which checks the react component mounting is a good solution.

If you do not like the above solution, here's what I specifically used to handle most of my React UI testing:

```
public static void WaitAndClick(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
{
     var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
     wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by));

     driver.FindElement(by).Click();
}
```

My issues with automating React UI involved elements taking too long to load. Most of the page would load, but the component I was trying to click would not exist sometimes. So I wrapped `Click()` in a `WaitAndClick()` method, to ensure the element is clickable before I try to perform the click. This worked for most of my cases.

Comment: I only just noticed how much effort you put into this answer as I've only just looked back at this question. Thank you very much fantastic information!

Comment: Glad to hear this is still helpful for you! Happy automating!

Comment: This is also the only solution I could work out with WebDriver.IO (with so much time wasted!)